# Search multiple columns for text in sequential way

Tags: nested, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe of 2 columns: col1 is the name, col2 is a text string as follows:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | Include Name2, Include Name3, Include Name4 |
| Name2 | "aa" |
| Name3 | Include Name5, Include Name6 |
| Name4 | Include Name6 |
| Name5 | "bb" |
| Name6 | Include Name7 |
| Name7 | "cc" |

My Target is: For Name1 I get the value for Name2 ("aa"), but for Name3 I need to read it again from Column1 and read Name5 ("bb") and again read Name6 from column1, and Name7 from column1 to reach for
the final values of (Name1 = "aa", "bb", "cc", "cc")

I'm a beginner in Python and appreciate any support or guidance, thanks

Comment: Ooo, a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).